# Java thread listener

Tags: java, list, queue, runnable

I would like to create a runnable class which contain a list inside. While running, thread will listen to any list changes and process all elements inside. That's my idea.

Below is my code but it still doesn't execute process() when I add new element to list or list changed by . Please give me some help.

```
public class QueueService implements Runnable {

    private List<Request> requestQueue;

    public synchronized void add(Request request) {
        if (requestQueue == null) {
            requestQueue = new LinkedList<Request>();
        }

        requestQueue.add(request);
        LOGGER.info("Added new request");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        LOGGER.info("Queue started...");

        while (true) {
            if (requestQueue != null) {
                process();
            }
        } 
    }

    private synchronized void process() {
        try {
            Iterator<VMRequest> requests = requestQueue.iterator();

            while(requests.hasNext()) {
                Request req = requests.next();

                // process each element and remove when done
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.info(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please understand that _doesn't work_ tells us absolutely nothing. Explain to us what you expect to happen and why. Explain to us what actually happens.

Comment: put infinite loop in your `run` mehod for listening on queue. It is exiting before anything goes in the list.

Comment: @Adi I edited my post with infinite loop, but it's still not work

Comment: Why don't you use a [queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) since this seems to be exactly what you want?

Comment: or use [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html). [Here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/blockingqueue.html) nice tutorial that can help you.